GKE cluster - difference in resource request/limits seen in pod manifest VS on node
I've observed a "weird" behavior of the GKE cluster, it seems that resource requests/limits set in pod/deployment are not respected (or wrongly interpreted) by nodes
Any idea what may be the reason for this behaviour and how to solve this? (it cause a lot of issues with resource allocation in cluster)
Example of a pod which runs with 50m CPU request, which are seen as 250m by node:
$ kubectl get pod core-worker-6bcf9d4877-5wqpb -n austria -o=jsonpath='{range .spec.containers[*]}{"Container Name: "}{.name}{"\n  Requests:\n    CPU: "}{.resources.requests.cpu}{"\n    Memory: "}{.resources.requests.memory}{"\n  Limits:\n    CPU: "}{.resources.limits.cpu}{"\n    Memory: "}{.resources.limits.memory}{"\n"}{end}'

Container Name: core-worker
  Requests:
    CPU: 50m
    Memory: 256Mi
  Limits:
    CPU:
    Memory: 1Gi

and now the node perspective:
$  kubectl describe node $(kubectl get pod core-worker-6bcf9d4877-5wqpb -n austria -o=custom-columns=NODE:.spec.nodeName)

...
Non-terminated Pods:          (12 in total)
  Namespace                   Name                                                     CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  Age
  ---------                   ----                                                     ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  austria                     core-worker-6bcf9d4877-5wqpb                             250m (26%)    500m (53%)  256Mi (5%)       1Gi (21%)      18m


I believe cpu/memory used by init containers/sidecars clutters things up. Please see this issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/issues/934

Turns out that the describe node showed the resource limits/request from initContainer, as pointed out by @RoarS.
